# How to redirect on other page when wp-content/uploads/?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect on http://www.janvajevu.com when user click on http://www.janvajevu.com/wp-content/uploads/.

As i have implemented following code but it create an issue when we upload image from "Media" menu in the backend.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^janvajevu\.com
RedirectMatch 301 /wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://www.janvajevu.com
```

Comment: "But it creates an issue" what is the issue?

Comment: Why would a user "click" on that? And why do they need to redirect?

Comment: Why upload media when you can't access it?

Comment: You are mixing mod_alias and mod_rewrite. You **can not** use rewriteCond with `redirectMatch`. You need to use [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). Also in your condition you need to specify to allow it from the SERVER so it doesn't block the upload. `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^127\.0\.0\.1 [OR] RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^yourserverIP`

Comment: starkeen, When i add that code it was creating issues like i can not upload images from "Media" menu from wordpress backend.

Comment: Dear Mike,When i have added the code i was not able to upload images from wordpress backend.

Comment: Dear,Panama Jack. thank you so much for replying me can you please let me know how to write code in order to prevent that upload directory access from users.